# How to use sawtooth identity-tp processor

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

> I am playing around with hyperledger-sawtooth. I have installed the
>   sawtooth in ubuntu machine but identity transaction processor is not
>   installed with sawtooth. so how can i use **identity-tp** command

Answer (score 2):

go into the sawtooth-core/bin folder where all the deafualt TPs will be there. You will find build_xxx_identity-tp. 
Start your validator, settings TP and run above shell script file from bin.
You will see log in your validator, that identity-tp is registered.

Comment: From a docker install, do you need to run this from inside the validator, shell or setting container or can it be run from the host machine?

Answer (score 2):

1. Install package `python3-sawtooth-identity`
2. To start a TP, including the Identity TP, just type it on the command line. For example,
   `/usr/bin/identity-tp -v -C tcp://localhost:4004`

For Docker, you normally run the Identity TP in its own container, just like other transaction processors.

For more info, see https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/cli/identity-tp.html

Edit: as requested, here's the Identity Transaction Processor Specification:
https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/master/transaction_family_specifications/identity_transaction_family.html

Comment: Please  let us know if there is a detailed documentation available for identity-tp.